# How is this array declaration in C possible?

Tags: arrays, c

```
int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

This way of declaration is not giving an error and the array is stored up till the 4th index, if I try to output arr[5] it will give garbage value.
Can anyone explain how this way is possible?

Edit:
I was trying to run the following code in an online compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int i;
    for(int i=0; i<6;i++){
        printf("arr[%d]=%d\n", i,arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buggy compiler?  It requires a diagnostic.

Comment: You might tell us what compiler you are using. You should get some diagnostic message about providing excess elements in array initializer

Comment: It's possible because the compiler is not required to refuse it.  Hmm, perhaps it _is_ required to refuse it. Add `-pedantic-errors` if you're using `gcc` or `clang`, `/permissive-` if you are using MSVC. The program has undefined behavior anyway though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will initialize only 5 elements of the array. The remaining initializers will be ignored. The compiler will emit a diagnostic message (warning).

```
<source>:11:23: note: (near initialization for 'arr')
<source>:11:25: warning: excess elements in array initializer
```

> This way of declaration is not giving an error and the array is stored
> up till the 4th index

This is correct - you need to read the warning messages and notes. ***Do not ignore warnings!!***

> if I try to output arr[5] it will give garbage value

You invoke Undefined Bahavour by reading outside the array bounds.

Comment: The standard requires a diagnostic for a constraint violation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ammended